# Zend - how to disable layout on a given action?

Tags: zend-framework, layout, view, zend-view, zend-layout

I have the following controller that, among other methods it has this one:

```
class EquipasController extends OccControllerAction {

    public function listaAction()
    {    
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    }
}
```

I was expecting that, when I do: 
http://www.example.com/equipas/lista/

the controller will execute and I will see no layout rendering on my viewport.

However, that's not the case. I get my home page rendered.

Where on ZF do we normally say: if an action doesn't exist a home page should appear?

Note:
If, instead of:
*http://www.example.com/equipas/lista/*

I do,
*http://www.example.com/equipas/adasdas21232131/* 
that doesn't exist.

I get the same home page rendering.

**What could be the cause for such a behaviour?**

A Zend Newbie,
MEM

Comment: Something wrong with my question? Should I provide more details? Am I saying something dummy? Please let me know. Stuck here.

Comment: Could you specify your problem? Do you want to disable the layout or do you want redirect to the homepage when an action doesn't exist?

Comment: Thanks. No. I don't want to disable the layout nor redirect to homepage when the action doesn't exist. What I want is, when we do: http://www.mysite.com/equipas/lista/ (SO, when we call the action lista) the layout isn't used. Why? For ajax calls for example. Thanks.

Comment: Solved. We also must enable that action on Acl. Otherwise nothing will run on it, hence, the layout will NOT disable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not answer your question directly (which you seem to have solved anyway), but to disable the layout and deliver a different view for AJAX requests, consider using the [AjaxContext](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.ajaxcontext) action helper.

Comment: Will that help me on solving some deep link issues?

Answer (score 23):

Add this inside your controller:

```
public function preDispatch(){
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); 
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in zf2

```
 public function indexAction()
    {    
        echo "json"
        return $this->getResponse();
    }
```